# Connecting google cloud bitnami SSH

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, bitnami

Google Cloud dashboard is very different and relatively difficult as compare to EC2, I have created a VM powered by LAMP, Now I want to put files on my server or SSH to it via File Zilla or Win SCP.

It didnt ask me to create the keys, I tried using bitnami username and password present at dashboard (with no key) but it is not authenticating. what should I do now ? I dont want to download whole gcloud sdk for just putting files.
Any option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add you ssh key to the machine by going logging into the Google Cloud Console then navigating to Compute Engine > VM Instances.

Click on your VM name, then choose edit at the top.

[image: Edit button]

Once you are in edit mode, you can upload an SSH key and save it.

[image: key upload]

After you added a key, you can ssh / scp like normal. See: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#standardssh

Comment: Trii Johnson it require key in special format, When I copy/paste it shows error, I generated key via ssh-keygen

Comment: Here is what I did, I launched the ssh in browser, throw the ssh-keygen commant, 2) I echoed the id_rsa pvt file and saved it in file, 3) converted it via putty , 4) tried using in winscp but it says server refused your file.

Comment: I tried it says Invalid key. Required format: <protocol> <key-blob> <username@example.com>

Comment: The link I posted says: `<username>: <protocol> <key-blob> <username@example.com>`

Comment: Finally I copied the stuff from id_rsa to authorized keys and it worked,